# How can i be sure that an google chrome api calls being succeeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to add a new bookmark by clicking on a button of a extension.When i click on a button, a dialog box comes.But when i click on an add button, it doesn't add to my bookmark. Below is my code:

```
$('#addlink').click(function() {
        alert('click on the add button');
      $('#adddialog').empty().append(edit).dialog({autoOpen: false,
        closeOnEscape: true, title: 'Add New Bookmark', modal: true,
        buttons: {
        'Add' : function() {
           chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId: bookmarkNode.id,
             title: $('#title').val(), url: $('#url').val()},function (){
                 if(chrome.runtime.lastError)
                    console.log('new bookmark added');                   
                 else
                     console.log('new bookmark add failed');
             });
           $('#bookmarks').empty();
           $(this).dialog('destroy');
           window.dumpBookmarks();
         },
        'Cancel': function() {
           $(this).dialog('destroy');
        }
      }}).dialog('open');
    });
```

What is wrong with that?No error messages are printing. My few more questions are,

1. How can i be sure an api calls, like here `chrome.bookmarks.create` works successfully?

2.I wanted to print a message in callback function, is my way correct to check, if the message prints under the callback function, that means, the api calls successfully happens?

Comment: You can check chrome.runtime.lastError in the callback.

Comment: @wOxxOm i trield like below, but didnt print anything.

chrome.bookmarks.create({parentId: bookmarkNode.id,
                 title: $('#title').val(), url: $('#url').val()},function (){
      if(chrome.runtime.lastError)
      console.log('new bookmark added');      
         else
       console.log('new bookmark add failed');
     });

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `chrome.bookmarks.create(object bookmark, function callback)`
   callback function to check whether api works successfully.

> 2. I wanted to print a message in callback function, is my way correct to
>      check, if the message prints under the callback function, that means,
>      the api calls successfully happens?

Yes, that means the api calls successfully happened.